# Applying single symbology definition to multiple TIFFs in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, geotiff-tiff, bathymetry

I have 143 separate TIFF files representing bathymetric data, all with different data ranges (high/low values). I want to create and apply a single symbology file having 6 levels corresponding to 6 discrete data ranges although individual TIFFs may only contain data with 1 or 2 of the 6 data ranges.

How do I do that in ArcMap 10.4?

Comment: Using ArcMap 10.4 or Arc Pro 2.x

Comment: Or QGIS? What software are you using?

Comment: I have access to QGIS but am much more familiar with ArcMap (10.4) and, to a lesser extent, Arc Pro (2.x).

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't merge the individual TIFFs into one mosaic?

Answer (score 1):

To apply consistent symbology to each of your TIFF files, open the properties of one in your table of contents, go to symbology, apply manual classification, and define the break points for the 6 classes you want to apply to your dataset. ArcMap will allow you to create breaks that fall outside the range of individual TIFFs, so it's not a problem if they have different data ranges.

[image]

Once you have your symbology classes defined for the first TIFF, right click on the layer in your TOC and Save as Layer File. Then for each new TIFF, open up the Symbology tab in Properties and click the folder icon at the top right to import symbology (circled in image). Click the folder icon in the window that opens up (circled in image) to browse to the location of the layer file you saved in the previous step.

[image]

It will be a little tedious to do this for each of your 143 TIFFs, but it will definitely work.

Comment: @ lamberj, I was aware of this workflow but wanted to see if there was a faster way. Thank you for confirming that I was on the right track ;-) Much appreciated!

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I'm sure there is a more automated way to do this. If I had that many separate layers to apply a style to I wouldn't want to import symbology every one individually either. You should edit your question to show that you've considered the "one at a time" import option but want something more automated. You'll be more likely to get good suggestions that way.

Comment: Have you tried using the Apply Symbology From Layer tool?  You can always use it in batch but it might more sense for your use to use a model?  It's in the Layers and Table Views Toolbox.  This is an alternative: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b282ba43695c401aa75d32336eaca82f

Comment: @ lamberj, just getting back to this now, will try what you suggest, thanks so much!